# How to get multiple rows from single row of table?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, union

Hi I have two tables with following structure

Students

```
 +------+------+------+-------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4  | Col5 | Col6 |
+------+------+------+-------+------+------+
|   01 | Hari | 20   |    80 |   21 |   81 |
|   02 | Nari | 20   |    67 |   21 |   76 |
|   02 | Lari | 25   |    87 |   26 |   96 |
+------+------+------+-------+------+------+
```

Here COl1= ID, Col2= Name,Col3= SubjectCode, COl4= Marks in Col3, Col5= subjectCpde, Col6= Marks for Col5

And another table called subjects

```
+------+-----------+
| Col1 |   Col2    |
+------+-----------+
|   20 | English   |
|   21 | Maths     |
|   25 | Chemistry |
|   26 | Physics   |
+------+-----------+
```

Here Col1= Subject Code, COl2= Subject Name 
which were referenced on in student table.

Now my query should retturn the result as follows. How it is achieved?

```
+---------+--------+------+
| Subject |  Marks | Name |
+---------+--------+------+
| English |     80 | Hari |
| Maths   |     81 | Hari |
+---------+--------+------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

Using two query, first query `subjectCode` by `English` ,second query `subjectCode` by `English`. then use `UNION ALL` to combine them.

```
SELECT sub.Col2 as 'Subject',stu.Col4 as 'Marks',stu.Col2 as 'Name'
FROM Students stu
inner join subjects sub on sub.Col1 = stu.Col3
WHERE stu.Col2 = 'Hari'
UNION ALL 
SELECT sub.Col2 as 'Subject',stu.Col6 as 'Marks',stu.Col2 as 'Name'
FROM Students stu
inner join subjects sub on sub.Col1 = stu.Col5
WHERE stu.Col2 = 'Hari'
```

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/513fe5/17